# If I think my mole is changing, what should I do?

Tags: dermatology

If I think a mole has changed, or my partner thinks they have noticed a change, what should I do about it? Is there any way of finding out for sure if a mole has changed?

Comment: Does it have hair growing? Have you seen a doctor about it before?

Comment: Diagnosis of a specific individual's medical condition is off-topic for [health.se]. If you or someone you know is facing the situation described in this question, please see a qualified physician in your area.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm a bit behind on meta musings, is a generalised question (see edit) ok?

Comment: To me this is, as you said, a "you should see a doctor" question (or at least give a call, he/she'll tell you whether visiting is needed). So you answerd it right and at the same time it should be closed...

Comment: (I am referring to this http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-should-we-do-with-questions-where-the-answer-is-clearly-see-a-doctor , even though it is still being discussed obviously)

Comment: After review of your edit, I voted to leave it closed. Your base question is still "what should I do", and the answer is still - "See a doctor".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Get to a doctor or dermatologist straight away

A changing mole is an indicator of possible melanoma. Melanoma spreads very quickly, and mortality rates rise fast if it is left to grow.

[Here is some information on what to look for, and potential indicators of melanoma](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Moles/Pages/Introduction.aspx) (UK NHS).

> Melanomas usually appear as a dark, fast-growing spot where there was not one before, or a pre-existing mole that changes size, shape or colour and bleeds, itches or reddens.

A specialist will be able to do a diagnosis, and advise you on future checks. If they think it could be a melanoma, they will remove the mole and perform a biopsy.